# how to fire a callback once data reader reads all result

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like

```
class ReadData{
 public IdataReader Execute(string sql){
    // Ado.net code here
    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
 }
}
```

This is the sample implementation and it works fine.
I am calling like this in caller

```
class caller{

  void CallMethod(){
    var reader = Execute("Sql query here");
    while(reader.Read()){
       logic here
    }
    //Here i need to get the out params after reading the resultset.
    //But the impplementation should in the class ReadData.
    //because that class has implementation to get the out params for the 
    //other type means, execute without resultset get only output params
 }
}
```

Some possible ways like calling the first method with callback and in that once the data is read completely then read the out params.

I don't know how to implement that stuff.

Any possible better ways to do ?
Please help me on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void Execute(string sql, Action<IDataRecord> action)
{
    using(var connection = new ...)
    {
        connection.Open();

        using(var command = new ...)
        {
            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while(reader.Read())
               {
                   action(reader);
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
var entries = List<object>();

Execute("Sql query here", row => entries.Add(row["Field"]));
```

Or you could try a more linqy appraoch:

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Execute(string sql)
{
    using(var connection = new ...)
    {
        connection.Open();

        using(var command = new ...)
        {
            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while(reader.Read())
               {
                   yield return reader;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which would allow something like this:

```
var list = Execute("Sql query here").Where(row => (int)row["Field"] == 17)).ToList();
```

However, this has some weird effects with defered execution if you don't materialize it properly.

Comment: u mean the second approach has got some problem or both the ways ?

Comment: The second approach is for people who know what they are doing. With the first one, it's way harder to make mistakes. Both work fine if used properly.